# Destructuring async properties in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, destructuring

Is there a way to get `async` properties with destructuring in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Like this:

```js
class A {
  public get x() {
    return this.getX()
  }

  private async getX() {
    return 5
  }
}

async function f(a : A) {
  const { x } = a

  console.log(x) // Promise
}
async function g(a : A) {
  // works as const x = await a.x
  const { await x } = a

  console.log(x) // 5
}
```

Comment: `const { x } = await a`

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky, I think it will return a `Promise` since it is waiting for `a`, not for `a.x`.

Comment: Okay, got it. Don't judge me, people often confuse `await a.x` and `(await a).x`

Comment: I'm afraid, there's no such syntax in JavaScript yet, you have to do `const x = await a.x`

Comment: No, there is not. Also it's weird to have getters that return promises (that are usually involved in side effects), what is your actual use case?

Comment: @Bergi, getters might return some values from the server (like `server.time`) which might require `async` operations (http request). Or they might be used to access some data cached by the implementation (like `file.content`) which... also might require some `async` operations.

Comment: @hopeless-programmer Yeah, one absolutely shouldn't use getters for that. Expose a method like `getXFromServer` and call it like `const x = await a.getXFromServer()`.

Comment: @Bergi, someone can use interfaces like `File` where `File.prototype.content` is implementation dependent and uses http or `readFile`. In this case there is no sense to implement this as a method. And there is also no sense to implement method without parameters starting with `get`. Just use getters.

Comment: @hopeless-programmer Either way, it's an expensive asynchronous operation, and should not be hidden inside a simple getter. Make it a method, document that it does something (i.e. has side effects) and how it can fail.

Answer (score 1):

If using utility function is allowed,
the following would work.
Its side effect is that the getters for all properties are executed.

```
const classToObject = async theClass => {
  const originalClass = theClass || {}
  const keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(originalClass))
  let classAsObj = {}
  for(const key of keys) {
    classAsObj[key] = await originalClass[key]    
  }
  return classAsObj
}


async function g(a : A) {
  // works as const x = await a.x
  const {x} = await classToObject(a);
  console.log(x) // 5
}
```